# Form to run PHP script and display output on same page

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a PHP script which downloads email attachments on a daily basis from cron. I would like to create a HTML form which can be used to run this script and others manually when necessary.

As the script runs there is a loop which displays the number of emails that have been run through and then at the end echos that the script has finished running.

I would like to be able to make it so that once the button is pressed on the form, a window will display these output's so that the user knows once the script has finished running.

The simple form I have so far:

```
<form action="test.php" type="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Download Attachments" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to achieve this? Right now the best way I can think of doing it is to redirect back to the form page after the script has finished running, but I would prefer it if everything could be on the same page so the user has a record of what scripts they have run, right in front of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's so simple to achieve that. Refer the following sample code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
         //code to be executed
    }else{
         //code to be executed  
    }
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP Script will only run if the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery then you can use [jQuery's Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it is a simple function that returns the result of page.

This JavaScript will run as soon as the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //tell the user that the script is still running

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getAttachments.php",
        success: function(data) {
            //data will contain the output from the page
        },
        complete: function() {
            //tell the user that the script has finished running
    });
});
```

You don't need jQuery to use ajax, but it makes it much easier and neater. You can see the version without jQuery here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

yes you can with a test like :

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
   // code to display your emails
}else{
   //code to display the from
}
```

so you will be always on the same page and it's PHP who decide what should be displayed to the user, no need for a redirect or whatsoever